# Dynamically populate checkboxes

Tags: php, javascript, html

Simple problem , 
I am trying to populate html form check-boxes dynamically, but when i try to do this by using checked property of the checkbox in html it not works correctly . The checkbox remain checked whether i use `checked='0' / checked='1'` , `checked='true' / checked='false'` and `checked='checked' / checked='unchecked'`.

although i solved it by applying extra checks in php as following...

```
while($contact = $db->fetchByAssoc($contacts))
{
$include_checked =( $contact['include'])? " checked={$contact['include']} ": "";
$opted_checked = ($contact['opted_out'])? " checked={$contact['include']} ": "";

$html.="<tr><td>{$contact['name']} </td>
            <td><input type='checkbox' {$include_checked}/> </td>    
            <td><input type='checkbox' {$opted_checked}/> </td>
```

Is there any better solution to do it???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `yes` to preselect it. Remove it to uncheck it by default

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="yes"/>
```

or `checked="checked"

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>
```

Or, but deprecated and not encouraged to use:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked />
```

Unchecked? Don't use any option at all. Just remove it. Through back-end there is no way to not select it. And of course this is not needed at all.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `checked` attribute does not matter. Don't set `checked` property at all when you want it unchecked.

```
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: yes i done that by php checks as in code, but why HTML has only one restricted option for checked property ? is there any other option? this is the question.

Comment: @mansoor I'm not aware of any restriction to `checked` attribute value (maybe in XHTML?). If there is `checked` attribute with any value, it will be checked, if there's no `checked` attribute it will be unchecked.